# Linear regression using Python (Pandas and Numpy)

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to implement linear regression using python.

I did the following steps:

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as n
data = p.read_csv("...path\Housing.csv", usecols=[1]) # I want the first col
data1 = p.read_csv("...path\Housing.csv", usecols=[3]) # I want the 3rd col
x = data
y = data1
```

Then I try to obtain the co-efficients, and use the following:

```
regression_coeff = n.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

And then I get the following error:

```
raise TypeError("expected 1D vector for x")
TypeError: expected 1D vector for x
```

I am unable to get my head around this, as when I print `x` and `y`, I can very clearly see that they are both 1D vectors.

Can someone please help?

Dataset can be found here: [DataSets](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/Ecdat/Housing.csv)

The original code is:

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as n

data = pd.read_csv('...\housing.csv', usecols = [1])
data1 = pd.read_csv('...\housing.csv', usecols = [3])

x = data
y = data1
regression = n.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

Comment: There is no *and use the following:*:

Comment: I did not get you.

Comment: You probably forgot to paste your code.

Comment: I was using the IDLE, whatever I have done till now is there in the question above.

Comment: For pandas-based regression and similar things you probably want to look into the statsmodels library:  http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/gettingstarted.html

Comment: @JohnE Can't you just help me figure out what wrong I have done?

Comment: Sorry, can't help debug code that I cannot see.

Comment: @Jeet1994 look at your post. You say "use the following: And then I get the following error". You're missing code in between `following:` and `And then I get`. Copy and paste that code if you expect anyone to help

Comment: I added the actual code @MikeMüller

Comment: @WayneWerner I will edit it. It missed my eye. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: @JohnE I edited the question. Sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
np.polyfit(data.values.flatten(), data1.values.flatten(), 1)
```

`data` is a dataframe and its values are 2D:

```
>>> data.values.shape
(546, 1)
```

`flatten()` turns it into 1D array:

```
>> data.values.flatten().shape
(546,)
```

which is needed for `polyfit()`.

Simpler alternative:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")
np.polyfit(df['price'], df['bedrooms'], 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike :) It worked perfectly. Can you please say why it worked when you added the flatten(), what did it actually do?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Python is telling you that the data is not in the right format, in particular x must be a 1D array, in your case it is a 2D-ish panda array.
You can transform your data in a numpy array and squeeze it to fix your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('../Housing.csv', usecols = [1])
data1 = pd.read_csv('../Housing.csv', usecols = [3])
data = np.squeeze(np.array(data))
data1 = np.squeeze(np.array(data1))

x = data
y = data1
regression = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

Comment: How is it a 2Dish array. It is clearly seen that I am taking only one column . Please guide me into a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) returns a `DataFrame`, which has two dimensions while [`np.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) wants a `1D vector` for both `x` and `y` for a single fit. You can simply convert the output of `read_csv()` to a `pd.Series` to match the `np.polyfit()` input format using [`.squeeze()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv('../Housing.csv', usecols = [1]).squeeze()
data1 = p.read_csv("...path\Housing.csv", usecols=[3]).squeeze()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. But, can you please give me some basic background, or at least provide a link for a place to refer and learn?